# Is it possible to turn old tomatoes into flour?

Tags: flour, culinary-uses, tomatoes

I saw a recipe that employed Tomato Flour - how do you turn tomatoes into flour?

Comment: What exactly would be the point of tomato flour?  What was the recipe for?  Maybe it would be easier to use flour + tomato paste?

Answer (score 6):

The recipe was most likely referring to [Tomato Powder](http://www.thespicehouse.com/spices/tomato-powder) which is available from the [Spice House](http://www.thespicehouse.com) in Milwaukee, WI.

I don't think you'd be able to produce the same result at home.  Even if the tomatoes could be dehydrated to the point where they are crisp enough to be ground, I don't think you could pulverize them fine enough very easily.  Even if it is possible, the trouble wouldn't outweigh simply purchasing the commercial product.

Answer (score 5):

I do this at home frequently; start by thinly slicing your tomato (roma tomatoes work best, because they're much meatier) and drying. You can do this using a food dehydrator, or in an open oven with low heat. This will take 5-10 hours, depending upon your tomatoes.

After your tomato slices are dried COMPLETELY, place them on a cookie sheet and freeze them. This will remove any remaining moisture.

Take your frozen and dried tomato slices and put small batches in a coffee grinder until they are powdered. If you want to ensure that there are no flakes, sift the powder through a flour sifter.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

The tomatoes that I dry in my dehydrator are easily dry enough to grind to a powder in my food processor. I remove the seeds but not the skin before I dry them. It would be impossible to remove the seeds after they are dried as they are cemented into the fruit at that point.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen Tomato Powder, but never Tomato Flour, I guess it could be a regional thing.

It's basically just dried tomatoes that are finely ground, as best I can tell, but I'd stem and seed them after they've been dried, as that's not going to contribute to the flavor.

Comment: Yes, and possibly remove the skins as well. The best way to do this is if you own a dehydrator. It would take a long time in a regular oven to get them dry enough to powder I think.